# Javascript Map a Collection

Tags: javascript, collections

**The Issue:**

I'm attempting to build a simple search tool.  It returns a search query by matching an id to another item with the same id. Without going into the complexities, the issue I'm having is that when my data was organized previously, the map function from javascript returned all the results perfectly. However, now that my data is structured a bit differently (a collection, I think?) ....the ids don't appear to be lining up which causes the wrong search results to show.

**The function in question:**

```
const options = this.props.itemIds.map((id) => (
  <Option key={this.props.itemSearchList[id].id}>
     {this.props.itemSearchList[id].name}
  </Option>
));
```

*When the data was structured like this it worked as expected:*

**Example of previous structure:**

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "name 0",
    tags: ['#sports', '#outdoor', '#clothing'],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name 1",
    tags: ['#sports', '#outdoor', '#clothing'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Name 2",
    tags: ['#sports', '#outdoor', '#clothing'],
  },
```

*Now that the data is a ?collection...the map function doesn't work as anticipated and it returns improper results or none at all:*  I've been able to use the lodash Map function on this structure successfully in the past.

**Here's a screenshot of the new data:**

[image]

**I believe a representative way to write out the example would be:**

```
const newItems = [
  0: {
    id: 0,
    name: "name here",
  },
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "name here",
  },
]
```

Any recommendations for making this work or need more info?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue entirely, but I believe it has to do with data structure and the map function from JS.  I can see results returning, but the id's are not lining up appropriately anymore.

Here's a visual representation of the misalignment.  The orange is the search input and it pulling the right result.  The green is the misalignment of what it's actually showing because of the data structure and mapping (I assume).

[image]

Comment: Your example of `newItems` doesn't work. You can't have an array of key value pairs in JavaScript.

Comment: Hey Charlie, Perhaps I didn't show my structure properly?  I've certainly worked with this setup before and have applied Lodash's map function successfully to it?  I posted a picture above the of the actual data.

Comment: Instead of `[` after the newItems thing do you mean to use `{` instead?

Comment: @charlie probably the whole confusion is created because the OP provided us with what his console showed, which isn't valid JSON (but one can still understand it IMO)

Comment: Sorry Charlie and Jonas! Thanks for trying to interpret me!  Feel free to point me in the right direction for highlighting this structure correctly in the future.

Comment: I think the confusion is you're looking in webtools, seeing those numbers and assuming it's a different shape, keyed by number or something. It's not. It's just your browsers friendly way of showing you what index each element is at, but it's still the exact same array that items is.

Comment: Mis-interpreting the "screenshot of the new data".  It's is an array of objects. It's being displayed labeling the individual array elements w/ their array indexes. That's not part of the structure per se. And, [1] shows "id" and the others don't so I wonder if the objects' members are consistent.

Comment: @radarbob The object at id: 1 is missing a description (empty string) so it's not showing that in the shorthand unless I expand the object in dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my simple solution:

```
const options = [];
    this.props.itemList.forEach((item) => {
      if (this.props.searchResults.includes(item.id)) {
        options.push(<Option key={item.id}>{item.name}</Option>);
      }
    });
```

Let me know what you think (to the group that tried to help!)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you were using index and lining that up with id as a sort of pseudo-key which is...beyond fragile. What you should be doing *is* keying by id (meaing `items`should be an object) and then having a seperate array that stores the order you want. So `items` would be an object keyed by id:

```
const items = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "name 1",
    tags: ['#sports', '#outdoor', '#clothing'],
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "name 2",
    tags: ['#sports', '#outdoor', '#clothing'],
  },
  9: {
    id: 9,
    name: "Name 9",
    tags: ['#sports', '#outdoor', '#clothing'],
  },
};
```

And then `itemIds` (which it appears you already have) is an array with the correct order:

```
const itemIds = [1,9,2];
```

And then they can be accessed in the right order by looping over that array, and getting the element by said key:

```
itemIds.map((id) => {
  const item = items[id];
  // do something with the item
}
```

---

Take a look at how Redux recommends normalizing state shape.

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Answer (score 1):

What you call "collections" and "maps" are actually arrays. Now one of the arrays has the objects exactly at the position in the array that matches the id:

```
items[5].id === 5
```

Now through sorting /mutating / whatever you change the order so that the element at a certain position doesnt have that as an id:

```
newItems[5].id // 7 :(
```

That means that you cannot access the item that easy anymore, you now either have to sort the array again to bring it into order, or you search for an object with the id:

```
newItems.find(item => item.id === 5) // { id: 5, ... }
```

Or you switch over to some unsorted collections like a real `Map`:

```
const itemsMap = new Map(newItems.map(item => ([item.id, item])));
```

So you can get a certain item with its id as:

```
itemsMap.get(5) // { id: 5, ... }
```

... but the whole thing doesnt have to do with `Array.prototype.map` at all.